# Provide progress indication during a lengthy start /wait command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-line

Part way through a batch file, there's a `start /wait` command, (invoking the silent install of a MSI file). As this install may take a while to complete, I'd like to animate, or show something, to the end user, indicating that the batch file is still working.

Is there, perhaps, a way to do that with looping code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there!

If you are installing a .msi package, you can use the "/passive" option to show only the progress bar while the program is install. In this example, I will use a PowerShell command to call a "msiexec.exe" with -wait argument:

```
Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList "/i C:\directory\msifile.msi /passive /norestart"
```

If you wanto to see all the other options, use:

```
msiexec.exe /?
```

[image]